# C# XmlSerializer, edit XML file without rewriting the whole file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I am currently working on a C# app, that has to serialize some simple object into
a given XML file.

For example, here is a simple example class... Let's say Human

```
   public class Human
    {
        private XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Human));

        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }

        public void Serialize()
        {
            StreamWriter stream = null;

            try
            {
                stream = new StreamWriter("data.xml");
                serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
                stream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I instanciate this class, set some values, and call the `Serialize()` method,
my `data.xml` file will look as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Human xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <name>Oscar</name>
  <age>20</age>
  <country>France</country>
</Human>
```

Now imagine that I have an object that contains a `List` of `Human`. Serializing this object will take time and ressources, and will generate a pretty big XML file.

If I wan't to edit a specific Human, or simply add a new one to my `List`, is there a way to edit/modify only a small part of the XML file ? Or do I have to re-serialize again the whole List and replace the XML file content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML simply isn't designed for this sort of operation. Your options are probably:

- Live with the file being big
- Use multiple files instead
- Use some other persistence (non-XML files, or a database) instead

Without knowing how big you mean by "big" or what your performance requirements are, it's hard to say which of these options is the most suitable - but I'd strongly urge you to carefully consider what your *actual* requirements are in concrete terms, and test them with the simplest option available.

Comment: As you said, dealing with some data that must be **editable**, cannot be done with XML files. As my real project is to reproduce a simple music library, where the user can add/remove some songs by specifying their path on the computer, I will use a SQL database.
I don't know why, I thought it could/should be done with some XML and serialization....

Comment: @MalteseFalcon: Well it *can* be done with XML... You just need to consider how much data you might have, and whether the result will really be too large

Comment: I may be done with XML, sure. But re-writing the whole file every time the user adds or removes a song is really nasty... Even if it doesn't takes a lot of ressources (I don't really know), it seems to be a really bad practice...

Comment: @MalteseFalcon: Well, in reality isn't it more likely that you'd add a whole album (or multiple albums) at a time? And unless you're a *huge* music fan, that's not likely to happen *that* often. Sometimes the simplicity of an inefficient solution is very compelling. (As an example, I use XML to store the notes/errata on csharpindepth.com. I have to rewrite the whole document every time I add a note - but that's relatively rare, so I don't care. Running a database would be *much* more complex.)